# Apache2 rewrite rule causing error

Tags: css, regex, apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache2 to redirect from port 80 to port 8080 of tomcat. My url is like

```
<IP address of server:8080>/mymodule/
```

after redirecting my url looks like,

```
<IP address of server>/mymodule/
```

Now I want to remove "/mymodule", so what I have done is used

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /mymodule/$1 [L,PT]
    JkMount  /* worker1
```

My problem is after doing this, my css,js, img files are not loading... Only my page is loaded, nothing else... How to rewrite expression to resolve this

If I am not using RewriteRule, my view page source look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mymodule/css/jquery.rating.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mymodule/css/style.css" />
<script src="/mymodule/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

If I am using RewriteRule, my view page source looks like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mymodule/css/jquery.rating.css;jsessionid=684675C2B02778B6B8D8CDC0918F7320" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mymodule/css/style.css;jsessionid=684675C2B02778B6B8D8CDC0918F7320" />
<script src="/mymodule/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js;jsessionid=684675C2B02778B6B8D8CDC0918F7320"></script>
```

Help me to resolve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `RewriteRule` like this:

```
 RewriteRule !^/?mymodule/ /mymodule%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,PT]
```